# Calling objective-c method from Swift error

Tags: objective-c, swift

I get an error when I try to call objective-c method from swift.
my objective-c .h class:

```
@class myType;
@interface myClass : NSObject
- (myType *)myMethod;
```

then I will create an object form myClass and try to call myMethod in swift (I have declared anObject of type myClass):

```
let a = anObject.myMethod();
```

but I get an error:
Value of type 'myClass' has no member 'myMethod'
If I change myType to something else, the error goes away. So it should be a problem of not recognizing myType in swift..

I appreciate any help

Comment: `@class myType;` is not sufficient, Swift needs to know the interface of that class.

Comment: Would you please give me an example?

Comment: The header file containing  `@interface myType .... @end`  must be included from the bridging header file.

Comment: Thanks... I added the myType header reference to my bridge class and it works. I will mark your answer as correct if you add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out the real problem for me was something else! 
I had to simply delete the derived data:

- Window -> Projects -> Derived Data -> Delete
- Clean Project
- Quit Xcode
- Open Xcode
- Build Project

Apparently, using swift I have to these steps more often..

Comment: Having the same problem, cleaned derived data, quit my xcode and still same error. In my case i can see in that my swift calls calling the objc method is present in the import module but still does not build : Value of type 'MyPrint' has no member 'createLayout'

Answer (score 5):

```
@class myType;
```

is only a "forward declaration" of that class. In order to call the

```
- (myType *)myMethod;
```

method from either Objective-C or Swift, the compiler needs to know the
actual interface declaration of that class. So "myType.h" or whatever
file contains

```
@interface myType : NSObject
// ...
@end
```

must be included from the bridging header file.

*Remark:* Class names should start with a capital letter.